# Python List formatting with small bracket

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add small bracket at the start and end of a Python list (Python 3)

My list is
list1 = ['1','2','3']

List needed is [('1','2','3')]

I know the solution may be simple, but I am not getting it.

Thanks in advance

Tried fstring and join

Comment: You mean you want it to output the string `"[('1','2','3')]"`?

Comment: its should remain list, just need to add small bracket at start and at the end.

Comment: What exactly is the point? Do you want a list containing a tuple?

Comment: Those are parentheses and they make a `tuple`. You've shown a list with 1 value (a 3 valued tuple). And it is created exactly as shown in your example `[('1','2','3')]`. If you want something different, you'll need to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to print a list in that formatting with a combination of an f-string and `str.join`:

```
>>> list1 = ['1','2','3']
>>> print(f"[({','.join(repr(i) for i in list1)})]")
[('1','2','3')]
```

Note that `repr(i)` adds quotes around the strings so that they print as `'1'` instead of `1`.

Note also that this is converting the list into a particular string, not adding anything to the list.  If you wanted to add the literal strings `(` and `)` to `list1` you could do:

```
>>> list1.insert(0, '(')
>>> list1.append(')')
>>> list1
['(', '1', '2', '3', ')']
```

But parentheses themselves aren't objects that you can add to a list.  If you want to construct an object that will render with parens, that's a `tuple`:

```
>>> list1 = ['1','2','3']
>>> [tuple(list1)]
[('1', '2', '3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

> its should remain list, just need to add small bracket at start and at the end.

So you want a tuple within a list? This works:

```
>>> lst =  ['1','2','3']
>>> lst = [tuple(lst)]
>>> lst
[('1', '2', '3')]
```

Note that this will cause differences in how the list is indexed, as to access the string `'1'`, you will have to use `lst[0][0]`

Comment: one thing I noticed is   using f"[({','.join(repr(i) for i in list1)})] --> returns a string, while [tuple(lst)]  returns a list....[tuple(lst)] works for me...Thanks again for giving the solution in such a short time

Comment: This works too: `repr([tuple(list1)])`

Comment: @vahndi that works if you want a string: per the OP: its should remain list, just need to add small bracket at start and at the end.

Comment: oh missed that - Fridays!

Comment: Join the club...